# Combine values from one column for the same primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a query that finds all medications entered into a pharmacy dispensing system on a particular day. It finds all administration times and creates a separate row for each.

```
PATIENT1 DRUG1  9:00AM
PATIENT1 DRUG1  1:00PM
PATIENT1 DRUG1  5:00PM
PATIENT1 DRUG1  9:00PM
```

I need it to combine all administration times in the same cell separated by a comma.

```
PATIENT1 DRUG1  9:00AM, 1:00PM, 5:00PM, 9:00PM
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select patient, drug,
       string_agg(time, ',') within group (order by time)
from t
group by patient, drug;
```

In older versions of SQL Server, the method uses `for xml`:

```
select pd.*,
       stuff( (select concat(',', time)
               from t
               where t.patient = pd.patient and t.drug = pd.drug
               order by time
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as times
from (select distinct patient, drug) pd;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm currently running Server 2016 and the STRING_AGG function is not available.

Answer (score 0):

for Example,In this table you hv your query result,

```
create table #temp (Med varchar(40),Times varchar(20))
insert into #temp values

('PATIENT1 DRUG1',  '9:00AM')
,('PATIENT1 DRUG1',  '1:00PM')
,('PATIENT1 DRUG1',  '5:00PM')
,('PATIENT1 DRUG1',  '9:00PM')
,('PATIENT1 DRUG2',  '02:00AM')
```

Then final query,

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Med, 
           Times
    FROM #temp
) AS src PIVOT(MAX(times) FOR times IN([00:00AM], 
                                       [01:00AM], 
                                       [02:00AM], 
                                       [9:00AM], 
                                       [1:00PM], 
                                       [5:00PM], 
                                       [9:00PM])) AS pvt;
DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Different timing will have diffrent Medicine.You need to write all `24 hour` timing inside PIVOT.

Also  `time format` inside `PIVOT` must match your result (`#Temp`) Time format.